# HTML format lost in email based on template

Tags: vba, outlook

I am sending emails using VBA with Outlook (Office 365), based on an HTML formatted template (.oft). It's somewhat heavy due to some images (*2Mb total*)
Many times it works fine.
Sometimes it loses the HTML formatting, and sends a plain text email (*same recipient, same template, same sender, same hardware / software*).

Two things I tried.

1. Slow down the loading of template (*application.wait*)
2. Setting the format explicitly as HTML

```vb
row = 2
Do While Sheets("invitees").Cells(row, 1) <> ""
    Email_Send_To = Sheets("invitees").Cells(row, 1)
    Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItemFromTemplate("K:\Path\Product Update.oft")
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:04 AM#) 'didn't help
    
    With Mail_Single
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = Email_Send_From
        .Subject = "Product Update"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'didn't help
        .Send
    End With
row = row + 1
Loop
```

I stripped the code down to

```vb
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItemFromTemplate("K:\Path\Product Update.oft")
MsgBox (Mail_Single.BodyFormat) 'the output is olFormatHTML as expected
Mail_Single.Close (olSave)
```

In the drafts, my email is consistently text only.

If I send the template manually, it goes as HTML (*both Outlook and Gmail render it accurately*).

Answer (score 3):

Try this just before .Send:

```
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 'Probably it will work anyway, but just to be sure.
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody 'A stupid assignment, but it works for me.
```

Comment: I tried many things -- none worked till I tried @Volare 's 'stupid assignment'.  That one liner (no need to set the `.BodyFormat`) was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the list of running add-ins in Outlook. Add-ins may change the body format in the background (in any Outlook's event handler).

```
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItemFromTemplate("K:\Path\Product Update.oft")
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:04 AM#) 'didn't help
```

Also, there is no need to add a delay right after the [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) call.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your template using `Office 365 Design Forms` and going to the *Developer* tab in *Outlook*.
Just call up your existing `.oft` then modify something trivial, and save it.